# Correr una web en segundo plano, para INSERT de datos

Tags: javascript, php, nodejs

Tengo una web, donde muestra los últimos datos ingresados en la BD (MySQL). Los datos son extraídos de SQL Server y enviados a MySQL por PHP. Todo funciona perfecto. El tema está en que para mantener esos datos actualizados constantemente, tengo que tener un archivo llamado `download.html` abierto. Ese archivo tiene:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
function changeNumber() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "traspaso.php",
    });
}
setInterval(changeNumber, 1000);
});
</script>
```

Y el archivo `traspaso.php` es donde tengo todas las Query hechas.

Mi pregunta es, ¿hay alguna forma de mantener activo ese archivo `download.html`sin tener que abrirlo?. Intenté con lo que vi en internet con esto:

> Dim WinScriptHost
> Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
> WinScriptHost.Run Chr(34) & "http://localhost:8081/Gestion_de_Comedores/Comedores_Totales/NQN-GNOC/download.html" & Chr(34), 0
> Set WinScriptHost = Nothing

Es un archivo VBS, pero lo que hace es abrirme la web. La idea es mantenerlo oculto en segundo plano.

Si alguien pudiera guiarme un poco, porque no sé por dónde arrancar o que hacer, que es lo mejor. Agradeceré mucho la info y opiniones.

**EDIT**

He estado investigando un poco de `Node.js` y tienen un método `forever` para poner en segundo plano un archivo. El tema es que le aplico lo leído a mi archivo `forever start app.js` y me dice:

> (node 3772) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'PadLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency (Use 'node --trace--warning ...' to show where the warning was created)

¿Alguien que sepa del tema, y me pueda dar una mano?, no sé si mi JS es para usar con Node.js o algo que este haciendo mal o me falte. De igual forma seguiré investigando.

**EDIT NUEVO**

archivo `traspaso.php` son muchos datos:

```
<?php

 include_once('Conexion\conexion.php');

 mysqli_set_charset( $conn, 'utf8mb4' );

 //QUERY SQL SERVER//

 $querySQLSRV = "SELECT TOP 1
        ID,
        panelName,
        readerID,
        tarjeta,
        apellido, 
        nombre, 
        descripcion,
        fecha

    from Factlog_Comedor
    order by ID desc";

   $resuestaSQLSRV = sqlsrv_query( $con, $querySQLSRV );

   /* MYSQL - QUERY */

    $queryMySql = "SELECT 
        ID,
        panelName,
        readerID,
        tarjeta,
        apellido, 
        nombre, 
        descripcion,
        fecha

    from Factlog_Comedor
    where ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) from factlog_comedor)";

    $respuestaMySQL = mysqli_query( $conn, $queryMySql );

    //QUERY ULTIMO ID MySQL//

    $queryMySql2 = "SELECT ID

    from Factlog_Comedor
    where ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) from factlog_comedor)";

    $respuestaMySQLMIN = mysqli_query( $conn, $queryMySql2 );

     //QUERY CANTIDAD DE REGISTROS EN MySQL//

     $queryMysqlContar = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM factlog_comedor";

     $respuestaMysqlContar = mysqli_query( $conn, $queryMysqlContar );

   //TERMINA LA SELECCION DE DATOS //

  if ( $resuestaSQLSRV == false or $respuestaMySQL == false or 
 $respuestaMySQLMIN == false or $respuestaMysqlContar == false )
  {
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ) );
 }

   //ULTIMO DATO INGRESADO EN LA TABLA MySQL//
 if ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $respuestaMySQL ) )
     {
$id = $row[ 0 ];
   ?>
   <tr>    
        <td>DATO MySQL:</td>
        <td><?= $row[ 0 ] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row[ 1 ] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row[ 2 ] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row[ 3 ] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row[ 4 ] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row[ 5 ] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row[ 6 ] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row[ 7 ] ?></td><br>
    </tr>

<?php

//ULTIMO DATO INGRESADO EN SQL SERVER//
}
if ( $row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resuestaSQLSRV ) )
 {
$id1         = $row1[ 0 ];
$panelName   = $row1[ 1 ];
$readerID    = $row1[ 2 ];
$tarjeta     = $row1[ 3 ];
$apellido    = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $row1[ 4 ] );
$nombre      = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $row1[ 5 ] );
$descripcion = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $row1[ 6 ] );
$fecha       = $row1[ 7 ]->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
  ?>
   <tr>    
        <td>DATO SQL SERVER: </td>
        <td><?= $row1[ 0 ] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row1[ 1 ] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row1[ 2 ] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row1[ 3 ] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row1[ 4 ] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row1[ 5 ] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row1[ 6 ] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row1[ 7 ]->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) ?></td><br>
    </tr>
   <?php
   }
   //EL DATO MAS ANTIGUO EN MySQL//
   if ( $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array( $respuestaMySQLMIN ) )
    {
   $id2 = $row2[ 0 ];
    ?>
   <tr> 
        <td>ULTIMO ID (MySQL): </td>
        <td><?= $row2[ 0 ] ?></td><br>
    </tr>
   <?php
 }

  //CANTIDAD DE REGISTROS MySQL//
if ( $row3 = mysqli_fetch_array( $respuestaMysqlContar ) )
{
$cantRegistro = $row3[ 0 ];
   ?>
   <tr> 
        <td>CANTIDAD DE REGISTROS (MySQL): </td>
        <td><?= $row3[ 0 ] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
   }

  // $id MySql 
  // $id1 SQLServer
   //compara si son diferentes los ID
  if ( $id != $id1 )
  {

//Si el id de MySQL + 1 , es igual a id1 quiere decir que faltaba el 
 ultimo dato
if ( ( $id + 1 ) == $id1 )
  {
    
    //Si la cantidad de registros es superior al limite actualiza, sino 
   inserta
    if ( $cantRegistro >= 10000 )
      {
        $queryUpdate = "UPDATE `factlog_comedor` SET `ID`= '$id1', 
 `panelName`= '$panelName', `readerID`= '$readerID', `tarjeta`= 
  '$tarjeta', `apellido`= '$apellido', `nombre`= '$nombre', 
  `descripcion`= '$descripcion', `fecha`= '$fecha' where `ID`= '$id2' ";
        
        mysqli_query( $conn, $queryUpdate );
        
        echo "<p style='color:green;'>UPDATE CORRECTAMENTE</p>";
        
      }
    else
      {
        
        $queryInsert = "INSERT INTO `factlog_comedor`(`ID`, `panelName`, 
            `readerID`, `tarjeta`, `apellido`, `nombre`, `descripcion`, 
         `fecha`) 
            VALUE (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare( $conn, $queryInsert );
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $stmt, "ssssssss", $id1, $panelName, 
        $readerID, $tarjeta, $apellido, $nombre, $descripcion, $fecha );
        
        mysqli_stmt_execute( $stmt );
        
        echo "<p style='color:green;'>INSERTADO CORRECTAMENTE</p>";
      }
    
    
  }
   else
  {
    //diferencia entre IDs
    //ejemplo id1(SQL) 100 y id(MySQL) 98
    $cantInserts = $id1 - $id;
    echo "SIN INGRESAR " . $cantInserts;
    
    for ( $i = 1; $i <= $cantInserts; $i++ )
      {
        $x             = $cantInserts - $i;
        $querySQLSRVID = "SELECT
                ID,
                panelName,
                readerID,
                tarjeta,
                apellido, 
                nombre, 
                descripcion,
                fecha

            from Factlog_Comedor
            where  ID = $id1-$x
            order by ID desc";
        
        $resuestaSQLSRVID = sqlsrv_query( $con, $querySQLSRVID );
        if ( $row4 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resuestaSQLSRVID ) )
          {
            $id4          = $row4[ 0 ];
            $panelName4   = $row4[ 1 ];
            $readerID4    = $row4[ 2 ];
            $tarjeta4     = $row4[ 3 ];
            $apellido4    = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $row4[ 4 ] );
            $nombre4      = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $row4[ 5 ] );
            $descripcion4 = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $row4[ 6 ] );
            $fecha4       = $row4[ 7 ]->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) ;
            
            //Si la cantidad de registros es superior al limite actualiza, sino inserta
            if ( $cantRegistro >= 10000 )
              {
                $queryUpdate = "UPDATE `factlog_comedor` SET `ID`= '$id4', `panelName`= '$panelName4', `readerID`= '$readerID4', `tarjeta`= '$tarjeta4', `apellido`= '$apellido4', `nombre`= '$nombre4', `descripcion`= '$descripcion4', `fecha`= '$fecha4' where `ID`= '$id2' ";
                
                mysqli_query( $conn, $queryUpdate );
                
                echo "<p style='color:green;'>UPDATE CORRECTAMENTE (FOR)</p>";
                
              }
            else
              {
                
                $queryInsert1 = "INSERT INTO `factlog_comedor`(`ID`, `panelName`, 
                    `readerID`, `tarjeta`, `apellido`, `nombre`, `descripcion`, `fecha`) 
                    VALUE (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                
                $stmt = mysqli_prepare( $conn, $queryInsert1 );
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $stmt, "ssssssss", $id4, $panelName4, $readerID4, $tarjeta4, $apellido4, $nombre4, $descripcion4, $fecha4 );
                
                mysqli_stmt_execute( $stmt );
                
                echo "<p style='color:green;'>INSERTADO CORRECTAMENTE (FOR)</p>";
              }
          }
      }
  }
   }
 else
 {

echo "<p style='color:red;'>NO ES POSIBLE REALIZAR EL INSERT - IDs 
IGUALES</p>";
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Y si creas un proceso que envíe los cambios periódicamente a MySQL sin que intervenga una página web? Con eso, no sería una página en segundo plano sino un ETL periódico (o una replicación o alguna cosa)

Comment: en realidad la web ``download.html`` únicamente tengo el script para que actualice el archivo ``traspaso.php``  es como tener el archivo ``traspaso.php`` abierto y darle a F5. Ese archivo hace todas las comparaciones, y agrega datos si hubiera nuevos por agregar. Pero no se como hacer para que mantenga eso activo, sin tenerlo en una pestaña :/

Comment: Lo necesito activo, ya que al ingresar el dato nuevo, el "personal" necesita verlo a los 10seg. aprox.

Comment: Pues es que una cosa es estar moviendo datos en segundo plano, y otra es estar entrando al sitio web y consultando los datos. Estás usando una cosa en frontend para resolver un problema de backend.

Comment: Entiendo, tengo que resolverlo de otra forma, con node.js puede ser que se haga?

Comment: hice un edit  con lo que pude investigar un poco

Comment: Puedes mostrar lo que contiene el archivo traspaso.php

Comment: lo agrego en un edit

Comment: Suena a que necesitas una forma de enviar eventos desde el Servidor al Cliente. Has investigado sobre la tecnología de [Websockets](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)?

Comment: Es justo lo que hace, enviar eventos del servidor al cliente.. solo que con PHP. Si investigue y leí. Pero tengo que aplicarlo, pero mientras tengo que tener esto funcionando.